# Why can't I set my layout to GridBagLayout anymore?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm getting an error when I set my layout to `GridBagLayout` but it worked just fine before.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GridBagLayoutTest {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
}
}
```

I'm getting an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method setLayout(LayoutManager) in the type JFrame is not applicable for the arguments (GridBagLayout)
```

Comment: *but it worked just fine before.* - did you compare your working code with this code to see what the difference is?

Comment: My "working code" isn't working ever since today.

Comment: Have you tried compiling from the console with javac?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import java.awt package since GridBagLayout class belongs to that package.

Comment: Compiler mistakes are EXTREMELY rare, if they can happen at all. It's not possible for it to stop working without being changed from one day to another. Maybe try reopening your IDE?

Comment: The code doesn't have any issues, I just tried it in my PC and it worked just fine. Try re-installing or updating your JDK.

Comment: I updated my JDK yesterday and im using the newest version lmao

Comment: Maybe that is the problem. The update can have go wrong. Try re-installing the update or downgrade to the previous working version.